# live Video streamming

Tags: macos, video, stream

Can any one tell me how to stream video  using mac osX , i need to write an application in mac os for video conferencing please let me know any prerequisites for making this application and what shud i learn for this .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do streaming or two-way videoconferencing? The latter is orders of magnitude harder than the former. If you just need streaming (one server, many clients), then [QuickTime Broadcaster](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/resources.html) will do what you want.

Comment: Well Many many thanks for your reply , acutely i need to design an application which capture the video by cam and send it to other end and i need to display the captured frame by cam on both  the end.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used [libcurl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to stream a video from youtube, [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) (from ffmpeg) to decode and parse the data into frames and finally [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) to display it on my Mac OS X.

If you are looking for ffmpeg/SDL code examples, you must check this out:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial02.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Josh Wolf, you might want to consider developing an Adobe AIR application (inherently flash, but via whichever OSes you choose), as it already has built-in components for capturing and streaming video.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great alternative for using this kind of service: tinychat.com

You can create a private room there and tell the password only for the people you need to talk to. The best reason for using tinychat.com is that you don't need to install anything.. It does works very well and quickly, and suports 9 broadcasts at the same time, with webcam, audio and/or text chat.